# AmazonHttpClient return status code 404 when endpoint exists

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, httpclient

I'm using `aws-java-sdk-1.12.457.jar`

I get the status code `404` when executing `AmazonHttpClient`, but when I use Postman I get the status code `403`

This is my code

```java
AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(false);

// Create AWSSecurityTokenService credentials
AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
        .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
        .withRegion(REGION).build();

// Create credentials
AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest().withRoleArn(this.roleArn)
        .withRoleSessionName(this.roleSessionName);
AssumeRoleResult roleResponse = stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest);
Credentials sessionCredentials = roleResponse.getCredentials();
BasicSessionCredentials credentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(
        sessionCredentials.getAccessKeyId(),
        sessionCredentials.getSecretAccessKey(),
        sessionCredentials.getSessionToken());

// Create request
DefaultRequest<Void> request = new DefaultRequest<Void>(SERVICE_NAME);
URI endpoint = new URI("https://domain/path/...");
request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
request.setHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.POST);
request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.setParameters(this.buildRequestParameter());

// sign AWS4Signer for request
AWS4Signer signer = new AWS4Signer();
signer.setServiceName(SERVICE_NAME);
signer.setRegionName(REGION);
signer.sign(request, credentials);

// Send request
ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
clientConfiguration.setConnectionTimeout(10000);
AmazonHttpClient httpClient = AmazonHttpClient.builder().clientConfiguration(clientConfiguration).build();

RequestExecutionBuilder requestExecutionBuilder = httpClient.requestExecutionBuilder();
requestExecutionBuilder = requestExecutionBuilder.request(request);
requestExecutionBuilder.errorResponseHandler(new ErrorResponseHandler());
Response<Void> response = requestExecutionBuilder.execute();

return this.buildResponse(response);
```

I think even if aws authorization failed, I should get status `403` not `404`.